# C++ template functions with the same name but different return type

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to make some file streamer that can read or write different types. Everything works except for the reading part with specific method. That method returns `std::unique_ptr<T>` when called and is a "wrapper" for another method that returns `T`. For some reason compiler does not use this method instead it tries to compile it with the other method (the one that returns `T`). The compilation fails because of this. I've already tried to search around internet but I can not find any accurate answer. Could you please help me with this.

The two methods I have defined:

```
template <typename T>
T read()
{
     T obj;
     obj.readFromFile<T>();
     return std::move(obj);
}
```

and

```
template <
  typename T,
  template<typename> class D,
  template<typename, typename> class Container
>
typename  std::enable_if_t<
  std::is_same<Container<T, D<T>>, std::unique_ptr<T, D<T>>>::value,
  Container<T, D<T>>
>
read()
{
    return std::move(std::make_unique<T, D<T>>(readFromFile<T>()));
}
```

The latter method is the one that I am trying to call.

When I write something like this:

`std::unique_ptr<A> AfromFile = fileStreamer.read<std::unique_ptr<A>>()`

compiler tries to compile it with the first method (`template <typename T> T read() {...}`) and the compilation fails. I could make this work if I made `unique_ptr object` first and than do the copy assignment to `*unique_ptr<A> object` but this is no good for me because i use some macro over those two functions and I cannot make `unique_ptr<A> object` or object A it self prior to calling the macro. Just for info I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Is there any way to make this work without any significant modification? I also found one suggestion that basically says you have to add a pointer parameter to one function and then call it with `static_cast<Obj>(nullptr)` as an argument but this does not count in my example.

Thanks for your help.

**Update:**
I just want to make a remark that all solutions below did work for me however the easiest way to fix my problem was solution provided by Barry.
Thx again for helping me!

Comment: You will have to call `fileStreamer.read<A, std::default_delete<A>, std::unique_ptr>()`...

Comment: You are right, indeed I am calling this method with the wrong number of args. After I put correct number of param like you suggested, the code compiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, while I understand your intent of:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> AfromFile = fileStreamer.read<std::unique_ptr<A>>();
```

You're not actually calling the function you think you are. You have two overloads of `read`:

```
template <class T> T read();
template <class T,
    template<typename> class D,
    template<typename, typename> class Container
> T read();
```

The first has one template parameter, the second has 3 (and some sfinae). But you're only calling `read()` with one template parameter, so the second overload - the one you want - isn't even an option.

For these cases, I like simply tag dispatching so that we can overload instead of having to specialize:

```
template <class T> struct tag{};

template <class T> T read() { return read(tag<T>{}); }

template <class T>
T read(tag<T> ) {
    T obj;
    obj.readFromFile<T>();
    return obj; // <== NB: no move() here! That inhibits RVO
}

template <class T, class D>
std::unique_ptr<T, D> read(tag<std::unique_ptr<T, D>> ) {
    /* unique_ptr case */
}
```

---

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. This solution was the easiest way to solve my problem. Ohh by the way I use std::move because I expect that all objects should have move/assign constructor.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you want partial specialization, and as partial specialization on function is not possible, you may forward to class:

```
template <typename T> struct helper
{
    T operator() const
    {
         T obj;
         obj.readFromFile<T>();
         return obj;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename D>
struct helper<std::unique_ptr<T, D>>
{
    std::unique_ptr<T, D> operator() const
    {
        return std::make_unique<T, D>(readFromFile<T>());
    }
};

template <typename T>
T read()
{
     return helper<T>{}();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot have two overloads of a function which only differ by return type. You must use SFINAE to make sure only one is enabled for any given template parameter.
2. The way you are trying to deduce the template parameters in the second overload is wrong. Currently, you have to specify `T`, `D` and `ContainerType` when you call the function. I sense you probably want to pass just one type and then deduce whether it is a `std::unique_ptr`.
3. You cannot call `std::make_unique` and specify a deleter type. You must call the `std::unique_ptr` constructor with a newly created object.
4. You don't need to explicitly move the returned `std::unique_ptr`.

This is one way to do what you want.

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
T readFromFile() { return T(); }

template<typename T, typename D>
void helper(std::unique_ptr<T, D>);

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_unique_ptr : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_unique_ptr<T, decltype(helper(std::declval<T>()))> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!is_unique_ptr<T>::value>>
T read()
{
     return readFromFile<T>();
}

template<typename P, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_unique_ptr<P>::value>, typename = void>
P read()
{
    using T = typename P::element_type;
    return P(new T(readFromFile<T>()));
}

int main()
{
  read<std::unique_ptr<int>>();
  read<int>();
}
```